# page range for printing algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

Some print dialogs give you an option to specify which pages (and page ranges) you want printed out.

```
1-10, 3, 4, 23-47
```

Is there a recipe/algorithm for this already out there?

Comment: Algorthims for what? Please be more specific.

Comment: Algorithm or function/library? Parsing this seems to be trivial. (Split strings on ','), split again on '-', using *int(x)* convert the strings to ints. Add all pages to a set. Expand ranges. Create a list from the set and sort it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def parse_range(astr):
    result=set()
    for part in astr.split(','):
        x=part.split('-')
        result.update(range(int(x[0]),int(x[-1])+1))
    return sorted(result)

print(parse_range('1-10, 3, 4, 23-47'))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47]
```

Comment: This is very nicely done. I am particularly fond of the use of x[0] and x[-1] to work with either single values or ranges.

Comment: Instead of `result = result.union(...)` I would use `result.update(...)`.

Comment: Thanks @Sven Marnach, that's better.

Answer (score 3):

It's a few years later, but I made a python package that provides a PageRange object. It's on github at https://github.com/taylorzr/PageRange, and on pypi at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PageRange/:

```
pip install PageRange
```

Usage:

```
from pagerange import PageRange

page_range = PageRange("1-10, 3, 4, 23-47") #-> PageRange("1-10,23-47")
page_range.range #-> "1-10,23-47"
page_range.pages #-> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47]

page_range.add_page(48)
page_range.range #-> "1-10,23-47"
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for this?

```
outer= text.split(",")
dashes= [ x.partition('-') for x in outer ]
ranges= [ (x,z) if y == '-' else (x,x) for x,y,z in dashes ]
[ (int(x),int(y)) for x,y in ranges ]
```